# SIOD error unbound variable while changing the voice in Festival

Tags: text-to-speech, festival

I am defining the new voice (Punjabi) in festival using diphone concatenation approach. I have created all the necessary files.
but while I tried to change the voice from English to Punjabi then i get SIOD error:

```
nandwani@ubuntu:~/fest/dcs_pbi_pn_diphone$ festival festvox/dcs_pbi_pn_diphone.scm "(voice_dcs_pbi_pn_diphone)" 
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : dcs_pbi_pn::dir 
closing a file left open: festvox/dcs_pbi_pn_diphone.scm
```

Please tell me solution for it .

Answer (score 2):

The error tells that variable value in your scheme code is undefined. To solve this define the location of the voice folder:

```
  (defvar dcs_pbi_pn::dir ".")
```

In the beginning of scm file.

It is better to follow Festvox book process instead of hand-edit scm files which you do not understand.

Comment: I am not getting it.......let me tell you what i have done yet, i am working on latest versions of festival. i have defined a phoneset in phoneset.scm features .i have made diphone list.i have recorded  nonsense words using audacity software .  calculated the start end and middle of diphone present in nonsense word  after that and added this data in .est file 
in lexicon.scm file , i have defined letter to sound rules in the following way.
( [ ਊ ] = u: )  ( [ ਕ ] = k )
to be continued ..........

Comment: continue .....
there is a code in lexicon.scm file 
 ;; utf8-sampa map based on unitran 
(if (probe_file (path-append dcs_pbi_pn::dir "festvox/dcs_pbi_pn_char_phone_map.scm"))
    (begin
  (set! dcs_pbi_pn_char_phone_map
     (load (path-append dcs_pbi_pn::dir 
    "festvox/dcs_pbi_pn_char_phone_map.scm") t)) (load (path-append dcs_pbi_pn::dir 
       "festvox/unicode_sampa_mapping.scm"))
what are these files . dcs_pbi_pn_char_phone_map.scm and unicode_sampa_mapping.scm . what these files conatain . what is the format for these files  . working on Punjabi an Indian lang.....

Comment: You can ask a separate question about it, preferably on festival mailing list.

Answer (score -1):

Your statement is unbounded. The entire statement needs to be bound in parentheses, i.e. "()".